# Apache POI. How to stream docx / XWPFDocument to ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, zip, apache-poi, docx

I have essentially the following code:

```
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream( outputStream );

for ( Person person: people ) {

         XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
         out.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( person.getName() ) );
         document.write( out );
         out.closeEntry();
}
```

When I run this, the zip file is generated, but the docx file inside is split into it's component parts, and it doesn't generate more than one docx expanded file.

Is it possible to stream multiple docx files to a zip file using apache poi?

Comment: The docx is already zipped, so are you just trying to package them together?  If so, you don't need to open the doc to do it, just zip them as individual files.

Comment: @awm Yes, I want to create a .zip file, full of the docx files. I am also unsure how to change the name of the generated docx file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need POI.. POI is used to disassemble the 2010+ office files to manipulate them internally.

You just need to zip them using: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.util.zip.ZipEntry

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. My example code was a little contrived, as I only wanted to include the essentially. I do however want to edit the document for each 'person' in the 'people' collection, and then save all the edited documents, with a new filename to a single zip file.

Comment: In theory you can do it all in one step using DocumentOutputStream from POI and adding that as a ZipInputStream as en entity, but from a practical and debugging point of view this is horrible option.